# webpack-dev-server Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'D:\System Volume Information'

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, webpack-dev-server

### After I reinstalled my Windows and cloning project from GitHub, I am getting npm Error: EPERM: operation not permitted D:\System Volume Information

In terminal I run:

```html
webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js
```

And it compiles all good but when I open my browser on http://localhost:8000/ it says:

```html
Internal Server Error
```

When I check terminal I can see:

```html
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'D:\System Volume Information'
```

---

So my webpack compiles all good, the problem is when I try to open it at localhost:8000

### Already tried

- removing node_modules
- npm cache clean --force
- npm install npm@6.4.0 & npm@6.3.0
- reinstalling node.js
- using port 9000
- running terminal as administrator
- reinstalling webpack-dev-server
- disabling kaspersky antivirus
- deleting files from C:\Users\.config\configstore\

```js
{
  "name": "site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "webpack.base.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js "
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-optional-catch-binding": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/template": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/types": "^7.1.3",
    "adjust-sourcemap-loader": "^1.2.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.3.1",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "debug": "^4.1.0",
    "detect-libc": "^1.0.3",
    "glob": "^7.1.3",
    "gsap": "^2.0.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^5.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "locate-path": "^3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "lodash._baseassign": "^3.2.0",
    "lodash._basecopy": "^3.0.1",
    "lodash.isarguments": "^3.1.0",
    "lodash.keys": "^4.2.0",
    "ms": "^2.1.1",
    "npm": "^6.5.0",
    "only": "0.0.2",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
    "pngquant-bin": "^3.1.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
    "pretty-error": "^2.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "svg-url-loader": "^2.3.2",
    "toposort": "^2.0.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "update": "^0.7.4",
    "util-promisify": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/parser": "^7.1.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@webpack-cli/init": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "critters-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-critical-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.4",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "purify-css": "^1.2.5",
    "purifycss-webpack": "^0.7.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.26.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.0.4",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

### Versions

- npm -v **6.5.0**
- node -v **11.4.0**
- Windows **10.0.17134**

Answer (score 2):

I solve this issue by opening Visual Studio Code in Admin Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem was because webpack-dev-server watched wrong files.

### Fix

Change your public path of webpack-dev-server and it should work